# Reading values from label in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many label and each of them has same class.My Label contains some information, which I need to read. How to read label attributes in Jquery. So far I could get object using $ but unable to get any value from its property.I need to get values for Id,Text, and title. Please help me to get those values .

```
$(".tagLabel").each(function (i, obj) {

            var lableId = ??  // what I need to do with obj here to get it
            var labelText=??
            var lableTitle=??


        });
```

Comment: What is the html of a typical label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$(".tagLabel").each(function (i, obj) {
    var lableId = obj.id;
    var labelText= $(obj).text();
    var lableTitle= $(obj).attr('title');

});
```

Please note that you have to wait until your page is fully loaded, wrap your code with:

```
$(function() {
    //Page fully loaded
    //Put you code here
});
```

Comment: If this solves the problem, please mark it as accepted (so people facing the same problem in the future will be able to spot it easily). You are welcome.

Comment: Yeah I tried to accept, StackOverFlow says , wait another 5 minute to accept ! I will accept as soon as it allows.Looks like they need a while !

Comment: Accepted! Thanks Ismail. I have another challenege now, but looks like I cannot post another question for next 90 minute. Please let me know if I can ask in comment section.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm afraid you cannot ! what type of challenge ? I will give hints !

Comment: I gave it many try and could solve it  finally ! It was about , load was not waiting till  content is loaded, hence I had to write some callback. In beginning, I was unable to comprehend why I could not see element. Thanks Ismail !

Comment: Now I have another problem , like in previous case we had Obj.text(), it provided us label text, how about checkbox? I would like to get the value whether the checkbox is checked !

Comment: Try to use `.val()` will return the checkbox value.

Comment: I could not see alert for 2nd one:              $(".listCheckBox").each(function (i, obj) {
                alert("hi check");
                alert(obj.val());

            });

Comment: Try `$(obj).val()`

Comment: If you want to hook checkbox change use `$(".listCheckBox").change(function() { alert($(this).val()); });`

Comment: Got it I was missing this : alert($(obj).is(':checked')); Thanks Ismail !